# How to get JustMocks test projects working in VisualStudio online

Tags: msbuild, telerik, azure-devops, justmock

I have started using VisualStudio.com build services for my continuous Integration. However some of my test projects use JustMocks and I can't find an easy way to get this working in the cloud.
Has anyone got any easy methods of doing this?
Do I need to create my own hosted build agent or is there another way?

Comment: After much googling and scratching of head and not wanting to make all the horrible activity changes for JustMock ( https://github.com/Moq/moq4 ), I have opted to switch to using Moq instead. All working nicely now.

Comment: BTW, JustMock Lite ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/JustMock/ ) has the same feature set as Moq and works without the profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JustMock provides [installation-free elevated mocking](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/integration-installation-free-elevated-mocking.html) specially for shared build servers. Depending on what build system you use, there are integration points for MSBuild, TFS Build and through the environment.

Comment: I saw that and checked out the video. It was so complicated messing with the activity etc., that I opted to look at another framework.

Answer (score 2):

If JustMocks required to be "installed" then you will need to either create your own agent or change your tool. To be honest I don't recommend using a framework that needs installed. I would ask Telerik about options.

JustMock should provide a Nuget package that you can reference so that you don't need to install anything on the build server.

Comment: Agreed, and that's what I did. Thanks.